# Stored procedure error - Converting varchar to int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure that returns the appropriate security group for a report that is based on a database lookup and the report path. If the security group name is found in the path, it return the group name. For example if the report path is 'http://reportserver/Reports/report/Accounting' and 'Accounting' is found in the lookup table, it returns 'Accounting'. I am getting an error that states I am trying to convert the `varchar` value to `int` but I don't see where it would be coming from. Can anyone see where it would be converting to integer?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[report_bus_unit_access] 
    @rpt_path NVARCHAR(200) 
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @rowcount int;
   DECLARE @i int;      
   DECLARE @secgroup varchar(20);

   SET @i = 1;      

   SELECT id = identity(int, 1, 1), a.* 
   INTO #secgroup 
   FROM 
       (SELECT DISTINCT security_group 
        FROM BPOCOM.dbo.report_groups 
        WHERE security_group IS NOT NULL) AS a

   SELECT @rowcount = COUNT(1) FROM #secgroup;

   WHILE (@i <= @rowcount)
   BEGIN
       SELECT @secgroup = security_group 
       FROM #secgroup 
       WHERE id = @i            

       IF PATINDEX('%' + LOWER(@secgroup) + '%', LOWER(@rpt_path)) <> 0
       BEGIN
           RETURN @secgroup                 
       END

       SET @i = @i + 1
   END
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to return a `security_group`, which is a varchar value - a stored procedure has to return an `int`.

If you want the `security_group`, then `select` it instead of `return`ing it.

Comment: Or, the OP could use an `OUTPUT` parameter, rather than a `SELECT`.

Comment: If you want to capture and use the value in an outside procedure or script, consider an `OUTPUT` parameter. It's relatively difficult to capture result sets from stored procedures.

Comment: Agreed on the output parameter - depending on how you're doing it, an output parameter may be a little bit less work.